# Why does the height of my header (as per it's BBox) equal 0 when the DOM Inspector shows its height is 17px

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating a charting API to be integrated with the software out company develops, however, I am running into a snag.

I create a heading (with a `<text>` element) and then query it to find out what it's height is. The DOM inspector tells me its height is 17px, but when querying the BBox, it comes back as 0.

I tried to replicate the problem on a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xtduc137/) but it worked perfectly.

Here is my entire script for the module in question.

Please note that this code is by no means complete, I was busy going through it when I ran into this problem. I have seen that this happens with my legend elements as well.

```
export default function render({
    selection = null,
    dataset = [],
    width = 0,
    height = 0,
    margins = 10,
    chartHeading = "Chart Heading",
    chartID = "noChartIDSpecified",
    scrollbarWidth = 14,
} = {}) {

    try {

        let resizeButtonsHeight,
            svgWidth,
            svgHeight,
            mainDivContainer,
            mainSVGContainer,
            chartHeadingContainer;

        async function createResizeButtons() {
            if(!selection.select("div.resizeButtons")[0][0]) {

                const buttons = selection.append("div")
                    .attr({
                        class: "resizeButtons"
                    });

                buttons.append("p")
                    .attr({
                        class: "maximise resizeButton"
                    })
                    .text('\x31');

                buttons.append("p")
                    .attr({
                        class: "restore resizeButton hidden"
                    })
                    .text("\x32");
            }

            return "Resize buttons created";
        };

        async function determineInitialDimensions() {
            resizeButtonsHeight = selection.select("div.resizeButtons").node().clientHeight;
            svgWidth = width - margins - margins - scrollbarWidth;
            svgHeight = height - margins - scrollbarWidth;

            return "Initial dimensions determined";
        };

        async function createMainContainers() {
            mainDivContainer = selection.selectAll(`div.${chartID}`)
                .data([dataset])
                .enter()
                .append("div")
                .attr({
                    class: `${chartID} chartContainer dashboardElement`
                })
                .style({
                    width: `${width}px`,
                    height: `${height - resizeButtonsHeight}px`,
                    top: resizeButtonsHeight
                });

            mainSVGContainer = mainDivContainer.selectAll("svg.chartSVG")
                .data(datum => [datum])
                .enter()
                .append("svg")
                .attr({
                    class: "chartSVG",
                    width: svgWidth,
                    height: svgHeight,
                    transform: "translate(" + [margins, 0] + ")"
                });

            return "Main containers created";
        };

        async function createChartHeading() {
            chartHeadingContainer = mainSVGContainer.append("text")
                .text(chartHeading);

            chartHeadingContainer
                .attr({
                    class: "chartHeading",
                    x: width/2,
                    y: function() {return d3.select(this).node().getBBox().height}
                })
                .style({
                    "text-anchor": "middle" 
                });

            return "Chart heading created";
        };

        async function initChart() {
            await createResizeButtons();
            await determineInitialDimensions();
            await createMainContainers();
            await createChartHeading();
        };

        return {
            initChart
        }

    } 
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies, I've reduced the code.

Comment: Check the value of `this`

Comment: @andreas I've checked it and it returns `<text class="chartHeading" x="200" y="0" style="text-anchor: middle;">Revenue by Sales Month</text>`. I checked it by printing `this` to the console inside of the function. That seems to be the right element?

Comment: I've noticed that if I remove it from the function scope, it works. This would mean that I would not be able to write a function to create the heading which is not ideal as the functions help with code organisation.

Comment: No harm meant, but some crititcal remarks/questions: 1) Why all those async/await? Given the code you provided there is no benefit in doing so, it just adds to the overall complexity, which might obscure your real problem (although I think it is somewhere else). 2) `d3.select(this).node()` is the same as just using `this`. 3) When using all that fancy ES6/ES7 stuff, why not also step up to D3 v4 as well? 4) How does the function `render()` get called?